# Dynamically create skills for Actions on Google via an exposed API?

Tags: rest, actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit

Is there an API exposed for Actions on Google, similar to what Dialogflow offers with their API? The only API-like flow I have found through my research is [this webhook flow API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/build/json), but that only deals with conversation requests, prompts, and responses, which I have already handled.

Ideally I'd like to be able to dynamically create "agents" and their conversation flows without having to use the AoG console, similar to what Amazon offers with [Alexa SMAPI](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/smapi-overview.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a full API to do everything that you want end-to-end. Some parts, like Dialogflow and fulfillment, can be automated, but it will still require some manual work in the Actions Console.

I had a conversation with another developer on this subject once. As a workaround, which is admittedly hacky, they decided to use the Puppeteer library to programmatically control a browser instance to fill in fields and click buttons.

That may not necessarily work when the console changes, and isn't a good substitute for an API, but it may work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. While clever, that solution is unfortunately much too unreliable and hacky. Nevertheless I will accept this answer because it's our only plan Z.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using [Google Dialogflow REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview)

Here are APIs for the agent :

[image]
There are many more APIs available for different operations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I said "similar to what Dialogflow offers" in my original question. Our team can't rely on Dialogflow, which is why we're searching for an Actions on Google solution.

Comment: just out of my curiosity, why you don't want to use dialogflow? This the platform from Google to create bots for "Actions on Google"

Comment: Company policy prevents me from answering in the fullest, however we would like to go as low level as possible for most vendors. Since Dialogflow interfaces with AoG we would ideally like to be able to directly communicate with AoG. We're keeping Dialogflow in mind though.